# Sender Policy Framework

Tags: spf

The Company i work for makes E-Mail Marketing for other companies. My Task was to look into SPF and I understand the Basic functions of it, but one question got raised when I looked deeper into it.
My question is, does "-all" overwrite "~all"? Here's an example with Netflix (done with command line):
This was the first request i sent:

> nslookup -q=TXT netflix.com

results in

> "v=spf1 include:_spf_ipv4.netflix.com include:_spf.google.com include:amazonses.com include:netflix.hosted.strongview.com -all"

Then this request:

> nslookup -q=TXT :_spf.google.com

results in:

> "v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all"

Then this one:

> nslookup -q=TXT :_netblocks.google.com

results in:

> "v=spf1 ip6:2001:4860:4000::/36 ip6:2404:6800:4000::/36 ip6:2607:f8b0:4000::/36 ip6:2800:3f0:4000::/36 ip6:2a00:1450:4000::/36 ip6:2c0f:fb50:4000::/36 ~all"

The request for _spf.google.com has "~all" and what would happen when the "~all" from the last request

> nslookup -q=TXT :_netblocks.google.com

would be "-all"?
Would the "-all" overwrite the "~all"? Or would the ~all from the last request be ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evaluation of the include mechanism only results in a match or not-match, so the ~all/-all from the include record does not overwrite the all mechanism from the original record. If a include mechanism matches, the whole check will then return a result based on the qualifier on that mechanism (in your case Pass since the default qualifier is +).

So the netflix.com check will return Pass if any of the included records match. If none of the includes match it will return Fail due to the -all in the "top" record.

In section 5.2 of the RFC there is a table that explains how the include is handled: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.2